# How to get the value after promise in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, callback, promise

I am comsuming an APIRest, with Javascript, with fetch, as follows:

```js
var c;

fetch('http://-:8080/CantidadPacientes')
  .then(a => a.json())
  .then( function(msg) {
        c = msg;
   });
   
console.log(c);
```

But when I printed the variable "c", I get undefined.
How I can will get the value of msg, in variable c. I need the value msg outside the fetch, before the execution of console.log("c")

Comment: For more info read: ]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: "*I need the value `msg` before the execution of `console.log("c")`*" - but at that point in time, the value *doesn't exist yet* - it's asynchronous! Your only choice is to move the `console.log("c")` inside the `then` callback.

Comment: then how can I wait for this value to arrive, because I need to load a component with that value after fetch, and I only get an undefined value on my web page.

Answer (score 2):

By the time `fetch` is resolving the `promise` the line `console.log(c)` is already invoked.

Try moving it inside the callback:

```
var c;

fetch('http://-:8080/CantidadPacientes')
  .then(a => a.json())
  .then( function(msg) {
        c = msg;
        console.log(c); 
   });
```

You can test it with a simple `Promise.resolve`.

Your code example (`undefined`):

```js
var c;

Promise.resolve('hi').then((msg) => {
  c = msg;
});
   
console.log(c);
```

And inside the callback:

```js
var c;

Promise.resolve('hi').then((msg) => {
  c = msg;
  console.log(c);
});
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> I need the value of "c", outside the block "fetch"

This is an asynchronous call. That means all of the global code (execution context) will run to completion and only then the callback (micro task in this case) will be allowed to continue.
As stated by others in comments, there are a lot of questions and great answers explaining asynchronous JavaScript.
Just follow the links.

Comment: I need the value of "c", outside the block "fetch".

Comment: but it is outside (global)

Comment: Yers because I need that variable c, is already after fetch.